# Convert links using Apache without redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to convert links from /s/categories/... to /s/blog/categories/... without redirection

For instance, from:
https://example.com/s/real-estate/whatever-else-links/

to:
https://example.com/s/blog/real-estate/whatever-else-links/

Similarly there are few other categories like real-estate that need to be converted from /s/categories/ to /s/blog/categories/

To make things simple I can enter the other categories logic separately since there are few.

Upon some research I tried the following in the .htaccess file that does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/s/real-estate/([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^/s/barcelona-real-estate/([^\.]+)$ /blog/real-estate/$1
```

Here is the rest of the .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /s/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /s/index.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/s/barcelona-real-estate/([^\.]+)$
  RewriteRule ^/s/barcelona-real-estate/([^\.]+)$ /blog/barcelona-real-estate/$1

</IfModule>
```

Please let me know how to convert the links at the web server level. Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "without redirection"? Do you mean you want both variants working simultaneously?

Comment: I mean without the 301 HTTP redirection code and without page redirection or refresh. Thanks

Comment: I want it so that if a visitor visits the page: https://example.com/s/real-estate/rest-of-the-link/ it shows https://example.com/blog/real-estate/rest-of-the-link/ in the address bar. Thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz Do my replies make sense?